# Alt + left click on some method in Xcode always lead me to the wrong method with the same name

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, click, alt

I'm write objective-c code in Xcode
I know that I can push alt + left click my mouse on the method name, and the Xcode will lead me to the method body.

However, It usually lead me to the method body in the other class with the same method name !!

I got some method named something like: "loadDataThread" or "getCacheFile" in most of my controller classes, and I don't want to rename each of them with some new names since the classes' names already explain itself clearly.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

---

Thanks Fonix for additional explanation, it always happened when I use sth like [performSelector:@selector( myMethod )]; to perform my method.

Comment: ive noticed it does that when you are clicking on a method that is inside a `@selector(methodName)` i think it goes to the first instance of that method name it can find because it cant tell which class this selector is from (even though it should just look at the file you are looking at first...). unfortunately i dont know of a fix

Comment: ya! You said right, it always happen when I use performSelector: ... to perform the method